# UK Expat returning to UK wih non UK/EU partner

Tags: united-kingdom, visa

I am a UK citizen by birth who has been living in Australia for the last 25 years.  I now want to return to the UK with my Australian citizen partner of 20 years. Does anyone know the full process involved, type of visa required etc.  I was initially advised they need to apply for a settlement visa which seems more geared for when the UK citizen is already in the UK.  Any advice/help greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is indeed a settlement visa that is indicated in this case. It does not matter whether you are already in the UK or are returning with your partner.

Comment: The full process is documented in books, on many websites and with lawyers - it's not really something we can write in a couple of paragraphs. Putting on hold as too broad for now.